# format KeyEventArgs.KeyData to display in UI

Tags: c#, winforms

Hi is there a way to format all the KeyData in KeyEventArgs.KeyData when i tried to convert it to string example i have a keydata of Control And Letter A If i do this

```
e.KeyData.ToString();
```

The Output would be A, Control

And i want it to be like this

Control + A Is there a way to format it? like that??

i am thinking to replace the char "," to "+" but still the out put would be A + Control i need to display the modifiers first before the letters

Comment: i need to format it using only the e.KeyData

Comment: Use String.Format or a StringBuilder instead of splitting the default string and trying to create a new one. It will be simpler, faster and avoid creating temporary strings you don't really need

Comment: Alternatively, e.Modifiers.ToString() + e.KeyCode.ToString()

Comment: The default Keys.ToString() method generates nonsense, confuzzled by the [Flags] attribute on Keys.  You could use System.Windows.Forms.KeysConverter.ConvertTo() instead.  It normally generates the shortcut key description in menus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've tried this code

```
string[] a = e.KeyData.ToString().Split(',');
```

splited the text and put some logic when displaying

Answer (score 1):

Since Keys, the type of keydata is an Enum decorated with FlagsAttribute Attribute (hence a bitmap) I think you'd have to redefine the ToString method.

Or else, you can parse ToString() result, convert into an array and switch components. However, I doubt that such a solution would work when you press combination such Ctrl+Alt+Shift+B ....